# How to set up People so that catkin_create_pkg can get the email address for -m and -a

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a package is generated using `catkin_create_package -m "John Doe" -a "John Doe"`, the `package.xml` that is generated contains `<author>` and `<maintainer>` tags with `@todo.todo` email addresses.  Is there some config file somewhere that needs to be modified or an environment variable set or some `usermod`/`groupadd` step that needs to be run?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191077/how-to-set-up-people-so-that-catkin_create_pkg-can-get-the-email-address-for--m-and--a/) by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2014-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [package template generator L82](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/blob/cc824225107a2c3de95d0c69867e5c8d9d55e619/src/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py#L82) -- No email is passed to the `Person` object constructor. No attempt is made to look it up on the system anywhere, either. Therefore, no, there is no setup step missing. The `@todo.todo` portions of the maintainer email and author email addresses must be replaced manually.

---

Originally posted by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) with karma: 207 on 2014-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-23**:
I'm sure the ROS team would welcome a pull request to improve this for your use case.

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-08-23**:
I agree. It requires a bit of discussion though:

My first instinct is to provide for a global dot file config similar to what git uses, except for using yaml as the markup language in the config file.

I would store it at $USER_HOME/.ros/config and create a catkin_pkg_config binary to set it up.